# NSTextView, appendString and error with NSConcreteTextStorage

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

It is my first time using `NSTextView` and I am having a hard time figuring out how it works, I have a line like this:

```
    [[commandHistoryTextView textStorage] appendString:outputString];
```

and I get this error:

```
2012-02-24 12:40:52.971 binoclean[37863:703] Exception detected while handling key input.
2012-02-24 12:40:52.971 binoclean[37863:703] -[NSConcreteTextStorage appendString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2cca10
2012-02-24 12:40:52.975 binoclean[37863:703] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x9bf55b67 __raiseError + 231
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x9b5c8149 objc_exception_throw + 155
2   CoreFoundation                      0x9bf59170 -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 256
3   CoreFoundation                      0x9bea7da9 ___forwarding___ + 457
...
```

Any comments appreciated, greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-appendString:` is a method on NSMutableString. NSTextStorage is a subclass of  NSMutable**Attributed**String. You could call `-appendString:` on the textStorage’s `mutableString` like so:

```
[commandHistoryTextView.textStorage.mutableString appendString:outputString];
```

Comment: You meant `[commandHistoryTextView.textStorage.mutableString appendString:outputString]`, right?

Comment: Oops. Yes. Forgot the `.mutableString`. That’s the problem of not typing this in Xcode. ;)